# Identifyimg Your Local Climate Category?

Tags: severe-weather

I have been reading *Canadian Wood Frame House Construction* and often the book will give building recomendations based on the local climate. It will say, if the enviroment is wet, you will need X. Or if your house is subjected to extreme winds you will need Y. But at no point does it decribe what conditions must be met for a climate to conform to any of these categories. Are these categories standardised? Are their maps or guides available to figure out if ones lives in a wet climate or what category of wind strength a site is subject to?

Comment: talk to someone at a gardening store ... they may know

Comment: Look at AgCan's Plant Hardiness Zone map, it may give you a good ideas.